# Is there a standard for modelling smart contracts such as ERM for databases?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-design

I want to document my Dapp including the "data structure" (i.e. the relationship between different contracts). Is there a good way of modelling smart contracts that anyone has used successfully?